# Rundeck - New Project creation and that folder not appears in Rundeck server

Tags: java, rundeck

When I am trying to create new Project in the rundeck UI and its not reflecting in Rundeck server project location path. Can someone please suggest to fix this issue.

Rundeck Version: 4.1.0-20220420
Launcher : war
OS: MAC

Answer (score 0):

By default, the newest Rundeck versions store the projects in the internal backend (H2 by default, but configurable with a [real database](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/database/#database-overview) like MySQL-PostgreSQL).

If you need the filesystem to store the `resources.xml`/`yml` files just use any path reachable by the `rundeck` user.

Comment: Can you please share if any example as mentioned in the second point.                            Framework.properties -- path mentioned as this framework.projects.dir=/Users/XXXXX/Documents/XXXXXX/Rundeck/projects     Still any configuration required.

Comment: Hi Team,  Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: Hi Rajesh, the resources.xml/yml is for the model source, you can put that file in any path reachable by rundeck. In another hand, you can still use rundeck without care of that path, now the project properties file is stored in the internal/real database, e.g: if you need to edit the "project.properties" file just go to Projects Settings > Edit Configuration > Edit Configuration file button (up to right).

Comment: Thank you for your inputs.. I wanted to setup multiple hosts in a single Node. How can we achieve this? For Example I have five hosts i need to execute the uname -a through a command or job. Can you please suggest.

Comment: 1) configure your model source with your target nodes 2) create a job, on nodes section you can use a filter to dispatch your job to all nodes, a filter example could be `.*`. It seems that you  need a good tutorial, take a look at this: https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/learning/tutorial/preparing.html

Answer (score 0):

File Based project are deprecated in 3.4.

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/upgrading/upgrading-to-rundeck-3.4.html#removed-support-for-file-system-based-project-definitions

As [MegaDrive68k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72465380/rundeck-new-project-creation-and-that-folder-not-appears-in-rundeck-server/72534004#comment128104968_72466709) mentioned Resource files can still be stored locally for Node Sources.